# kendo UI splitter does not work in IE11

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

I am not able to get KENDO splitter work in IE11. It works fine in chrome.
here is a [jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/TvbLW/1/) for this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#splitter').kendoSplitter({
        panes:[
        {collapsible:true,size:'100px'},
        {collapsible:true,resizable:true}
        ]
    });
});
```

Open this in chrome it works, but in IE11 it does not work.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: IE 11 was released in 10/2013, the version of Kendo UI you're using is from 2012 - try reproducing with a current version first

Comment: Same Issue with current version too.     http://jsfiddle.net/TvbLW/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a version of Kendo UI that is compatible with the respective browser version. 
Your example works fine with version 2013.3.1316, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#splitter').kendoSplitter({
        panes:[
        {collapsible:true,size:'100px'},
        {collapsible:true,resizable:true}
        ]
    });
});
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/2sY6b/).